# Get maximum percent from csv

Tags: batch-file

```
subject score studentid
xx   23.22% 1
yy  34% 2
zz  55.2%   3
xx  88.66%  4
yy  23.76%  5
zz  78.04%  6
```

How to get max % and student id for each subject?

Comment: @stack - you're starting to venture into performing actual data processing.  I'd strongly recommend some other tool than cmd scripting. There are just too many places where batch files don't behave well for this type of processing. Use vbscript, perl, basic, python - almost anything besides Windows/DOS/cmd scripting.  See this answer for a pointer to a good book on batch files as well as more details on why I advise you to use something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180754/best-free-resource-for-learning-advanced-batch-file-usage/180767#180767

Comment: No perl but batch. As your script has some problem in comparing... how can we do numeric comparison?

Answer (score 0):

here's a vbscript you can try

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set e = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
strFile = objArgs(0)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine=objFile.ReadLine
    s = Split(strLine," ")
    subject =s(0)
    score= Left(s(1),Len(s(1))-1)
    studentid=s(2)
    If Not d.Exists(subject) Then
        d.Add subject, score
        e.Add subject, studentid
    Else
        If score >= d.Item(subject)  Then           
            d.Item(subject) = score
            e.Item(subject) = studentid
        End If
    End If
Loop
j=d.Keys
For Each stritems In j
    WScript.Echo "Subject:"&stritems & ", Score: "& d.Item(stritems) & "%, StudentID: " & e.Item(stritems)
Next
```

output

```
C:\test>type file
xx 23.22% 1
yy 34% 2
zz 55.2% 3
xx 88.66% 4
yy 23.76% 5
zz 78.04% 6

C:\test>cscript //nologo test.vbs file
Subject:xx, Score: 88.66%, StudentID: 4
Subject:yy, Score: 34%, StudentID: 2
Subject:zz, Score: 78.04%, StudentID: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some sort of collection to handle the totals for each subject, this might help

```
@echo off 

  set CountXX=1
  set CountYY=2


  set This=XX
  call :Resolve Count%This%
  echo %RetVal%


  set This=YY
  call :Resolve Count%This%
  echo %RetVal%

  set /a Count%This%=%RetVal% + 2 

  call :Resolve Count%This%
  echo %RetVal%

goto :eof


:Resolve


  for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%a in ('set %1') do set retval=%%a

goto :eof
```