# Batch file error, "unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, dos

In a Windows Batch File in DOS, I am receiving the the following error:

```
45.0.31322.0 unexpected at this time.
```

The numbers `45.0.31322.0` are the contents of the `AgtVersion` variable.

Here is the code:

```
if agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0==agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0 set AgtVersion=45.0.31322.0

:: Identify HPSA Agent Version
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('get_info.bat ^| find /i "agentVersion: 4"') do @set hpsaAGT=%%x

:: Checks agent version and store in new variable
if %hpsaAGT%==agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0 set AgtVersion=45.0.31322.0

:: THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE:
:: the above line throws a: "45.0.31322.0 unexpected at this time."

if %hpsaAGT%==agentVersion: 40.0.0.1.106 set AgtVersion=40.0.0.1.106
if agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0==agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0 set AgtVersion=45.0.31322.0

:: Display HPSA Agent Version and store in txt file
echo %AgtVersion%> c:\temp\hpsa_agent\hpsaAGT.txt
echo Current HPSA Core : %AgtVersion%
```

What does this error message mean?

Comment: use double-quotes, if your string contains Spaces: if "%hpsaAGT%"=="agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0" set AgtVersion=45.0.31322.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [%x was unexpected at this time. batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190295/x-was-unexpected-at-this-time-batch-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a variable to an unquoted string with spaces on it. DOS interprets the `agentVersion:` and `45.0.31322.0` as two distinct tokens.  The second token is unexpected.

```
if %hpsaAGT%==agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0
```

Should be:

```
if "%hpsaAGT%"=="agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0"
```